# Missing SharePoint list template in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: list, templates, sharepoint, visual-studio-2013

I have a strange problem. When I try to add a new "List" to my SharePoint 2013 project in Visual Studio 2013 it is impossible because there is no "template" to choose from. In the books there is a "(default) option that I am missing in my environment. (See picture),
And yes, I have the latest Office and SharePoint sdk installed by Web Installer. SOmething very simple I am missing ? Any help is [image: No template to choose]appreciated !   BR/Christer

Comment: For the new coming visitors, check how you can install office developer tools for [**Visual Studio 2017**](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/missing-sharepoint-template-in-vs2017/) & [**Visual Studio 2015**](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/office-sharepoint-template-missing-in-visual-studio-2015/) & [**Visual Studio Community 2013**](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/missing-officesharepoint-template-in-visual-studio-community-2013/)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you need to create a site (i.e teamsite) to the adjacent SharePoint-server to get a "default" option when creating a list in Visual Studio. URL of the new site must be added to project settings.

Comment: Couldn't find the option to add the URL (VS2013/SP2013), however the Default option appeared after creating the site and closing / re-opening Visual Studio.